# Start MainActivity or launcher manual

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-lifecycle

Is that's possible when user open my app to lunch Activity depends on something or lunch another activity not mainActivity if some happened.

My problem is that I have tow activities LogInActivity and BrowseDataActivity inside browseData I have Viewpager uses fragments which means that I can't use fragments instead of activities because you can't have fragments inside fragment.

if user is logged in then start BrowseDataActivity other wise LogInActivity is that possible?

I think I saw some code working around
Useing java script even I could load my views depending on.... but I don't wanna do that or use java scripts I could work around but useing stupid way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set LoginActivity as main activity and in LoginActivity.onCreate start the other activity if the user is already logged in

OR

Create an other activity (let's call it SplashScreenActivity) with something like this in onCreate :

```
setContentView(R.layout.myview);
boolean loggedIn = ...;
Intent i;
if(loggedIn)
   i = new Intent(this, yourActivity.class);
else
   i = new Intent(this, LogInActivity.class);

 startActivity(i);
```

Sorry I cant add code tags because i am on my mobile

Comment: Not sure what you mean but in LoginActivity if the user is logged in don't render any view (set an empty view)

Comment: Maybe you can set a other activity as main activity. This activity would be blank and it would act as a splash screen.

Comment: Please check my answer it an implementation with help from andryr and my own interpretation of your needs

Answer (score 0):

Just a modification of the above code it seems you want only two activities only. Lets get the requirements

1. Only two activites
2. Show BrowseActivity only if logged in
3. if not logged in show LoginActivity

Simple

In Browse Activity.

```
public boolean isLoggedin = prefs.getBoolean("isLoggedIn",false);
...
onCreate(){
 if (isLoggedIn)
setContentView(R.layout.browseActivity)
else{
intent i = new intent(this,LoginActivity);
startActivity(i);

}
```

Now in LoginActivity.

```
onCreate(){

//Code for loggin in possible conncecting to a server etc... whatever your implementation is
//If successful

SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("user_Data",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
ed.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
ed.commit();
//As the user is now logged in as they got this far...take them to the browse activity!
Intent i = new intent(this,BrowseActivity.class);
startActivity(i);

//else they are not logged in so show a "try again dialog"
```

}

This complements all of the requirements.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

well i know no one answer this question, but i want to answer my own question to help anyone facing same problem.

## **Problem**

#### i have LogInActivity and BrowseDataActivity "with Swipe Tabs"

we can write code in LogInActivity check if user loggedIn then show BrowseDataActivity remove LogInActivity from **Stack** else load LogInActivity views but problem is that Activity Window **Animation** when user is loggedIn first LogInActivity Window **Animation** then BrowseDataActivity Window **Animation**  if you could remove this animation every thing is cool but i will solve this problem by using Fragments.

## **solution**

we will have one Activity called **MainActivity** something like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/viewPager"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
       android:visibility="gone"></FrameLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

,we will have 1 Fragment **LogInFragment** what ever it's looks like 
and BrowseDataActivity's Swipe Tabs as you can see we have viewPager

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(isUserLoggedIn()){
      setUpSwaipTabs();// setUp Tab and Viewpager
    }else{
       showLogInFragment(); // load your Fragemtn 
                            //in FrameLayout id=fragment_container and show
                            // and hide viewpager.
    }
}
```